# Calculate new column in pandas dataframe based only on grouped records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with various events(id) and following structure, the df is grouped by **id**  and sorted on **timestamp** :

```
id | timestamp | A | B
1  | 02-05-2016|bla|bla
1  | 04-05-2016|bla|bla
1  | 05-05-2016|bla|bla
2  | 11-02-2015|bla|bla
2  | 14-02-2015|bla|bla
2  | 18-02-2015|bla|bla
2  | 31-03-2015|bla|bla
3  | 02-08-2016|bla|bla
3  | 07-08-2016|bla|bla
3  | 27-09-2016|bla|bla
```

Each **timestamp-id** combo indicates a different stage in the process of the event with that particular **id**. Each new record for a specific **id** indicates the start of a new stage for that event-id.

I would like to add a new column **Duration** that calculates the duration of each stage for each event (see desired df below). This is easy as i can simply calculate the difference between the timestamp of the next stage for the same event id with the timestamp of the current stage as following:

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].shift(-1))
df['Duration'] = df['End'] - df['Start']
```

My problem appears on the last stage of each event id, as i want to simply display NaNs or dashes as the stage has not finished yet and the end time is unknown. My solution simply takes the timestamp of the next row which is not always correct, as it might belong to a completele different event.

Desired output:

```
id | timestamp | A | B | Duration
1  | 02-05-2016|bla|bla| 2 days
1  | 04-05-2016|bla|bla| 1 days
1  | 05-05-2016|bla|bla| ------
2  | 11-02-2015|bla|bla| 3 days
2  | 14-02-2015|bla|bla| 4 days
2  | 18-02-2015|bla|bla| 41 days
2  | 31-03-2015|bla|bla| -------
3  | 02-08-2016|bla|bla| 5 days
3  | 07-08-2016|bla|bla| 50 days
3  | 27-09-2016|bla|bla| -------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['Duration']  = df.groupby('id')['timestamp'].diff().shift(-1)
```

If I understand correctly: groupby('id') tells pandas to apply .diff().shift(-1) to each group as if it were a miniature DataFrame independent of the other rows. I tested it on this fake data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1]*5 + [2]*3 + [3]*4
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-1')
duration = sorted(np.random.randint(30,size=len(df)))
df['timestamp'] += pd.to_timedelta(duration)
df['A'] = 'spam'
df['B'] = 'eggs'
```

but double-check just to be sure I didn't make a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `apply`

```
def timediff(row):
    row['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(row['timestamp'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
    return pd.DataFrame(row['timestamp'].diff().shift(-1))
res = df.assign(duration=df.groupby('id').apply(timediff))
```

**Output:**

```
  id   timestamp duration
0  1  02-05-2016   2 days
1  1  04-05-2016   1 days
2  1  05-05-2016      NaT
3  2  11-02-2015   3 days
4  2  14-02-2015   4 days
5  2  18-02-2015  41 days
6  2  31-03-2015      NaT
7  3  02-08-2016   5 days
8  3  07-08-2016  51 days
9  3  27-09-2016      NaT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution also works. However slower from @DalekSec so i will accept his answer.